# How to put the condition on User table with condition on subject table

Tags: laravel

Need to find the record with either first_name of the User table equal the keyword or subject of the TeacherSubject matches the keyword but 'step_completed' should equal '5' and 'is_approved' should equal '1' from the User table even if the orwhereHas condition is true.

```
$condition_array['radius'] = 25;
$condition_array['lat'] = $request->input('lat');
$condition_array['lng'] = $request->input('lng');
$condition_array['keyword'] = $request->input('keyword');
$sorting_type = $request->input('sorting_type');
$condition_array['filter'] = $request->input('filter');
if($sorting_type != ""){
    if($sorting_type == 0){
        $order_column = 'first_name';
        $order_order = 'DESC';
    }
    if($sorting_type == 1){
        $order_column = 'first_name';
        $order_order = 'ASC';
    }
}else{
    $order_column = 'id';
    $order_order = 'ASC';
}
$teachers = User::select('id','email','first_name','last_name','profile_picture','country_code','mobile')->with('teacherSubject')
    ->where(function($query) use($condition_array){
        $query->where(['step_completed'=>5,'is_approved'=>1]);
        $query->where(['first_name'=>$condition_array['keyword']]);
        $query->orWhereHas('teacherSubject', function ($query1) use($condition_array){
            $query1->where('subject',$condition_array['keyword']);
        });
    })
    ->orderBy($order_column,$order_order)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Need to find the record with either first_name of the User table equal the keyword or subject of the TeacherSubject matches the keyword but 'step_completed' should equal '5' and 'is_approved' should equal '1' from the User table even if the orwhereHas condition is true.

So if I would translate your statement into a query, I think it should look like this:

```
$teachers = User
    ::select('id','email','first_name','last_name','profile_picture','country_code','mobile')
    ->with('teacherSubject')
    ->where(['first_name'=>$condition_array['keyword']])
    ->orWhere(function($query) use($condition_array) {
        $query->whereHas('teacherSubject', function($teacherQuery) use($condition_array) {
            $teacherQuery->where('subject',$condition_array['keyword']);              
        })
        ->where(['step_completed'=>5,'is_approved'=>1]);
    })
    ->orderBy($order_column,$order_order)
    ->get();
```

This way you have 2 conditions:

- users.first_name == keyword OR
- teacher_subject_user_id == users.id AND teacher_subject.subject = keyword AND users.step_completed == 5 AND is_approved == 1

If any of both is true, it will show up as a result.

Please let me know if it works :)